# MUI DataGrid custom cells and space button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a `DataGrid` with custom cells which are `TextField`components. When I'm typing something inside the `TextField` it's working well until I push the space button, instead of putting space in `TextField` it's changing focus to the last row or just doing nothing. Can someone help with it? Here is my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-currying-7du4sy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `stopPropagation()` to `onCellKeyDown` `events` prop in `DataGrid`.

Like as:

```
<DataGrid
    ...
    onCellKeyDown={(params, events) => events.stopPropagation()}
/>
```

in your example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-dhawan-671nqb?file=/src/App.js